# Django widget form for get_or_create

Tags: django, django-forms, django-widget

I have a Select widget but I need list all of values about a field of Model, and create new values of these field at the same input.
With select I can list and choose one value, but can't create news.
Whith textinput I can create but not list.

What widget form can I use?

Comment: fielf, is that the word or a typo ?

Comment: fielf is fielD, sorry.

Comment: Handle this scenario using Customer Javascript code. No preferred way is available for this situation.

Comment: @AnupYadav That is the solution that I have taken, thanks.

Comment: this is old version of django autocomplete light  http://django-autocomplete-light.readthedocs.io/en/master/tutorial.html#creation-of-new-choices-in-the-autocomplete-form ,which let you create new choice as well as choose existing value i could not find the latest version of the docs